# Python if error in a loop continue loop from next iteration

Tags: python, loops

I have such code:

```
for i in range(0,5):
  try:
      print(f"opened some_file_{i}")
  except Exception as e:
      print(f"error opening some_file_{i}")
      return
  print(f"i = {i}")
```

After exception, I need contuinue the loop from the next iteration, but not continue code `(print(f"i = {i}")`

How can I do it?

I tried to use a break, continue, pass statements and return

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. The expected behavior and difference from the provided code is hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, continue works

```
for i in range(0,5):
  try:
      print(f"opened some_file_{i}")
  except Exception as e:
      print(f"error opening some_file_{i}")
      continue
  print(f"i = {i}")
```

So if I had an exception, ***continue*** will skip this loop iteration

Comment: why do you need continue, once you catch the exception, it will go to next iteration anyway

Comment: @Epsi95 - I think the commented parts shouldn't be executed, so `continue` is necessary. 
But the question is hardly understandable.

Comment: yes, then, they should be put in try block, I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you have handled the exception properly it should continue on to the next iteration. You do not require break, continue, pass or return statements.
When you try to break or return the control will exit out of the loop/ function.
Example:

```
    for i in range(0,5):
  try:
      print("Hello {}".format(i))
      if i == 3:
          raise Exception("Wrong file path error")
  except Exception as e:
      print(e)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u164o.png)